# Can I migrate a Windows 10 with a license key to another computer using dd?

Tags: dd

Not trying to do anything malicious or violate copyrights. Just out of pure curiosity.

If dd creates a full clone of a disk, will it work if I use dd to make a full copy of windows 10 with a license key to another drive and boot it on another computer and have it still worked?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can you help me with my software licensing issue?](https://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-issue)

Comment: Win10 identifies your machine by its bios (efi) id + disk controller id. If you somehow can solve that these remain, for example by fine-tuned virtualization settings, problem solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally it would detect a hardware change, and you'd need to activate it again.  That's a typical disaster recovery scenario, where your old computer was destroyed and you need to recover from backup.

Windows 10 encourages you to link a Microsoft Account to your computer.  I'm not sure what complications would occur if two installations were signed in from the same product key.

Comment: But let's say it's something like ubuntu, dd should work fine as a full backup right?

Comment: That's right.  I'm saying it will work for Windows 10 also, re-activation is pretty normal thing to do and you shouldn't have license issues.  I have a few PCs that did the Windows 7 -> Windows 10 free upgrade, in that case a Microsoft Account might be necessary to migrate hardware.

Comment: Ok. Thank you for your valuable information.